# A continuous real function $f$ satisfies $f(2x)=3f(x),\forall x\in \mathbb R$.If $\int_0^1f(x)=1$,then

Tags: calculus, integration

A continuous real function $f$ satisfies $f(2x)=3f(x),\forall x\in \mathbb R$.If $\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x)=1$,then find the value of the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_1^2f(x).$

---

I do not have any idea how to tackle this problem,the answer given in my book is $\displaystyle\int_1^2f(x)=5$,i guess we need to find out the period of the function $f(x)$.But i do not know how to find that.
Please help me.

Comment: suggestion - try calculating $\int_0^2 f(x)\, dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x = 2u \Rightarrow dx = 2du \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{0}^2 f(x)dx = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f(2u)du = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 3f(u)du = 6 \Rightarrow \displaystyle \int_{1}^2 f(x)dx = 6 - 1 = 5$

Comment: To Kf-Sansoo, can we solve above functional equation.

Comment: You mean $f(x) = 3f\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right) = 3^2f\left(\dfrac{x}{4}\right)...= 3^nf\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)$...and that's all you get.